# How do I cite both author and year in biblatex-mla?

Tags: biblatex, citing, mla-style

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to cite both the author and year, similar to what you get with `biblatex`'s `\textcite` i.e. Author (year), when using `biblatex-mla`. Right now I'm using a quite inefficient method:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
    title     = {{Seinte Katerine}},
    editor  = {S.R.T.O. d'Ardenne and E.J. Dobson},
    year      = {1981},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    address   = {Oxford}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
    According to \citeauthor{katherine} (\citeyear{katherine})...
\end{document}
```

If anyone knows how to do this more efficiently, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, your example doesn't have an `author` field, so that's the first obstacle I'd address. `biblatex` does have the `\DeclareCiteCommandCommand`, which you can use (the preferred method, but less easy to implement for a novice). Then there's always the hack: `\newcommand\citeauthyear[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}` -- which you'd use as `\citeauthyear{katherine}` in your example.

Comment: Can't you use `\textcite`? It is a standard `biblatex` command... Please don't use `minimal` for examples!

Comment: @jon That's not a problem. It has an `editor` and that's enough. More worrying, though, is the fact that the file has no bib entries in it at all...

Comment: I'd consider this a bug in `biblatex-mla`. Although the command is intended to depend on the style, it should be implemented and it should be implemented in a way which works in the flow of text i.e. it should replace the subject of the sentence. Not to adhere to that when creating a non-standard style or not to implement the command at all is just making life unnecessarily difficult for users.

Comment: @cfr -- Oops! I meant `bibkey`, not `author`.... (It was meant to be somewhat tongue-in-cheek.)

Comment: Hi, @jon and @cfr, thanks so much for your help. I'm definitely somewhat of a novice so I appreciate your suggestions and apologize for my mistakes (e.g. using `{minimal}` - I couldn't figure out how to upload the actual files so I made a very small example, sorry). The `biblatex-mla` documentation references commands like `\autocite` and `\citeauthor` so I assumed that commands like `\textcite` wouldn't be compatible, and actually when I try to use `\textcite` it gives me the whole citation in parentheses, e.g. (Author year). Please let me know what I can do to help you help me. Thanks again!

Comment: The very small example is absolutely the right thing to do. What @cfr meant was that the `minimal` class was not meant for constructing "minimal" examples by end-users (for various reasons, not important here). It is better to do exactly as you did, just with a class like `article` or `book` or as the actual problem demands. By the way, there is nothing particularly 'wrong' with my suggested hack, it's just not very flexible. (E.g., complex author lists will probably come out all mangled and not in the format you want ... but maybe not.)

Comment: @jon Okay, thank you so much; your hack was actually exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, so I will go ahead and use that, at least for now. I will also start looking into learning how to work with things like `\DeclareCiteCommand`. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Sorry. Yes. the example was perfect. I just meant don't use the `minimal` class, as @jon said. By the way, you can only 'ping' one person per comment. So this will ping jon (and you because it is your question), but your comment only pinged jon because it ignored the second attempted ping. (Probably why jon pinged me, I think.) I think you should put this in as a bug/feature request for `biblatex-mla`. The only reason you don't get an error is because `biblatex` has a fallback definition of `\textcite` which just uses `\cite`. But, really, I think the style should support it.

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I changed the class to `article` so your question is perfect now!

Comment: @cfr I don't mind at all, thank you so much for your corrections, suggestions, and patience with me being a new member on the forum and everything. I will put that in as a feature request to `biblatex-mla`. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @jon Since the OP was very happy with your solution would you care to make it an answer so we can close this?

Comment: @moewe -- No problem.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the `biblatex-mla` documentation suggests that this kind of author-year reference is not a standard *citation* command as far as the MLA guidelines go, so I presume this is why no such command is provided for.

You can create your own command with:

```
\newcommand\citeauthyear[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
```

This has at least one shortcoming: by default, it will not work with `hyperref` -- which may not be a big deal.  It will also not get "tracked" by the MLA ibid-tracker -- I'm not sure if this is a good or bad thing.  You need to decide what the output of this sequence should do:

```
\citeauthyear{<key1>} wrote about this \autocite{<key1>}
```

I think it depends on how you use this command. My vague memory of MLA rules (from my undergraduate days many years ago now) is that MLA expects you to "bracket" your citation sort of like: `name ... <ideas from "name"> ... (page)`. If so, then tracking is probably a good thing.

So another solution is to create your own more orthodox command via   `\DeclareCiteCommand`.  Here's a pretty basic one:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\aycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:mla:authyear}}%
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\citereset}

\newbibmacro*{cite:mla:authyear}%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printnames{labelname}\space
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}}
```

Here, by default, `hyperref` will work, and the command is not tracked. You can change the tracking by removing the `\citereset` in the `\aycite` definition.

Here's a complete example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{katherine,
    title     = {{Seinte Katerine}},
    editor  = {S.R.T.O. d'Ardenne and E.J. Dobson},
    year      = {1981},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    address   = {Oxford}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=red]{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\aycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:mla:authyear}}%
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\citereset}

\newbibmacro*{cite:mla:authyear}%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printnames{labelname}\space
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}}

% This version does not get "tracked" by `biblatex-mla`
\newcommand\citeauthyear[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt

% Baseline citation
\autocite[100]{katherine} \citereset


% These two paragraphs are equivalent
According to \citeauthor{katherine} (\citeyear{katherine}); \ldots
\autocite[100]{katherine} \citereset

According to \citeauthyear{katherine}; \ldots
\autocite[100]{katherine} \citereset


% These two commands paragraphs produce identical results; if you'd
% rather get the \aycite command tracked, take out the \citereset
% commands in the \aycite definition
According to \aycite{katherine}; \ldots
\autocite[100]{katherine}
\citereset

According to \aycite{katherine}; \ldots
\citereset% <-- this is the difference between this paragraph and the one above
\autocite[100]{katherine}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very thorough answer. Needless to say that I find the `\DeclareCiteCommand` approach much more appealing than the "stuff several `\cite...`s into one `\newcommand`" approach.

Comment: @moewe -- Indeed. Though I must admit I preach "best practice" noticeably more often than I follow it in my own documents. (Though I do try, or at least try to try, to be good.)